# Получения списка подписчиков Instagram

Tags: instagram

Здравствуйте.

Передо мной стоит задача, получить информацию о подписчиках заданных пользователей инстаграм, конечно, по возможности.

Посмотрев доки Instagram Api нашел, что только для текущего пользователя, под которым залогинены можно получить список подписчиков:

*https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN*

Подобная конструкция не работает:

*[https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user_id}/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/%7Buser_id%7D/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN)*

Вопрос о получение полноценного доступа к апишкам пропускается.

Как это можно сделать, возможно не через api?

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это возможно.

Например, есть [пример бота](https://github.com/LevPasha/instabot.py) на Python'e для Instagram'a.

В нём используется файл [userinfo.py](https://github.com/LevPasha/instabot.py/blob/master/userinfo.py) - для получения списка подписчиков не через API в обход через http://ink361.com :

сначала получаем юзера через

```
ui.search_user(user_name="danbilzerian")
```

Затем с помощью этих строк на Pythone происходит получение первых 10 подписчиков этого юзера, а затем вывод их ников:

```
ui.get_followers(limit=10)
print(ui.followers)
```

Comment: Судя по всему это не работает, по крайней мере по описанию. Work with userinfo.py (does not work after June 1 2016).

Comment: @user2572457 в мае пользовался ботом, всё было нормально, сейчас не заметил. Попробуйте всё равно, можно пошурстить этот сайт.

Answer (score 1):

Поймал запрос фиддлером, посмотрел на него, ничего необычного нет, можно получить список подписчиков. На этом и остановился.